# GCP Kubernetes doesn't find libgcc_s for a Elixir Dockerfile project

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, elixir, google-kubernetes-engine

## Context

Currently putting online for the first time an Elixir/Phoenix app on Google Cloud and Kubernetes, (I found a tutorial that I follow a tutorial => [run an Elixir/Phoenix app in containers using Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/elixir-phoenix-on-kubernetes-google-container-engine)), I'm getting stuck at what seems to be the last step : [Deploy to the cluster](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/elixir-phoenix-on-kubernetes-google-container-engine#deploy_to_the_cluster) due to some error I haven't found a fix for.

### The app

The elixir app is an **umbrella app** with two phoenix app, each one with a port (on for the admin website, the other for the general website) and three other elixir app.

There is a custom docker for dev (using docker-compose), and another **Dockerfile for production**, which is the following one (separated in two parts, I guess the first one is for the image building and the second is for kubernetes):

```
# prod.Dockerfile
FROM elixir:alpine

ARG app_name=prod
ARG phoenix_subdir=.
ARG build_env=prod

RUN apk add --no-cache make build-base openssl ncurses-libs libgcc libstdc++

ENV MIX_ENV=${build_env} TERM=xterm

WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN apk update \
  && apk --no-cache --update add nodejs npm \
  && mix local.rebar --force \
  && mix local.hex --force
COPY . .

RUN mix do deps.get, compile
RUN cd apps/admin/assets \
  && npm rebuild node-sass \
  && npm install \
  && ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js \
  && cd .. \
  && mix phx.digest

RUN cd apps/app/assets \
  && npm rebuild node-sass \
  && npm install \
  && ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js \
  && cd .. \
  && mix phx.digest
RUN mix release ${app_name} \
  && mv _build/${build_env}/rel/${app_name} /opt/release \
  && mv /opt/release/bin/${app_name} /opt/release/bin/start_server


FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add make build-base --no-cache openssl ncurses-libs libgcc libstdc++

ARG hello

RUN apk update \
  && apk add --no-cache postgresql-client \
  && apk --no-cache --update add  bash ca-certificates openssl-dev \
  && mkdir -p /usr/local/bin \
  && wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 \
  -O /usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy \
  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy \
  && mkdir -p /tmp/cloudsql
ENV GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID=${project_id} \
  REPLACE_OS_VARS=true
EXPOSE ${PORT}
EXPOSE 4011
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=0 /opt/release .
CMD (/usr/local/bin/cloud_sql_proxy \
  -projects=${GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID} -dir=/tmp/cloudsql &); \
  exec /opt/app/bin/start_server start
```

Which is called by `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```yaml
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
  args: ["build", "-t", "gcr.io/hello/prod:$_TAG",
       "--build-arg", "project_id=hello", ".",
       "--file=./prod.Dockerfile"]
images: ["gcr.io/hello/prod:$_TAG"]
```

## The steps

(re)building the image

```sh
$> gcloud builds submit --substitutions=_TAG=v1 .
```

Then create a deployment

```sh
$> kubectl run hello-web --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello:v1 --port 8080
pod/hello-web created
```

Check if the deployment went well (spoiler: it doesn't)

```sh
$> kubectl get pods
NAME                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
hello-web   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          15s
```

Check the log

```sh
$> kubectl logs {POD-NAME}
```

Which display the following error:

## The error

```sh
2021/08/09 23:49:15 current FDs rlimit set to 1048576, wanted limit is 8500. Nothing to do here.
2021/08/09 23:49:15 gcloud is not in the path and -instances and -projects are empty
Error loading shared library libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp)
Error loading shared library libgcc_s.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp)
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __cxa_begin_catch: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt24__throw_out_of_range_fmtPKcz: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _Znwm: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt20__throw_length_errorPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __cxa_guard_release: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZNKSt8__detail20_Prime_rehash_policy11_M_next_bktEm: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __popcountdi2: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt29_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalancebPSt18_Rb_tree_node_baseS0_RS_: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt17__throw_bad_allocv: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_appendEPKcm: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE9_M_createERmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_incrementPKSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __cxa_end_catch: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __cxa_guard_acquire: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZNKSt8__detail20_Prime_rehash_policy14_M_need_rehashEmmm: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt19__throw_logic_errorPKc: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZSt18_Rb_tree_decrementPSt18_Rb_tree_node_base: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEE7reserveEm: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __cxa_rethrow: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _Unwind_Resume: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZdlPvm: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
...
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __cxa_pure_virtual: symbol not found
...
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __cxa_pure_virtual: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE: symbol not found
...
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE: symbol not found
Error relocating /opt/app/erts-12.0.3/bin/beam.smp: __gxx_personality_v0: symbol not found
```

## What have I tried

Though I know almost nothing, I still tried to modify a little bit the Dockerfile, without success. I also search on Google the libgcc error without any success.

That's about it, as I don't have clues were to look other than that.

So, any advises to make it works ?

## Other actions

Delete the pod, then get the image's tags and clean it

```sh
$> kubectl delete pod hello-web
$> gcloud container images list-tags gcr.io/hello/prod
$> gcloud container images delete gcr.io/hello/prod@sha256:...
```

## Edits

### Edit 1 (12/08/2021 19:04)

- Update the Dockerfile with the latest version of it
- Add another action list

**Result : nothing changed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after hours of test, trying of things, I just changed the strategy and focused on the image version instead of the Dockerfile.

```sh
$> gcloud builds submit --substitutions=_TAG=v1.1 .
$> kubectl run hello-web --image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello:v1.1 --port 8080
```

I didn't changed it before because I wanted to keep the same version between the build and the app.

The other thing I changed is the `cloudbuild.yaml`: I removed the dash in front of the name.

Theses two action made the build run in the pod.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your question has been asked on the Elixir forums already:

https://elixirforum.com/t/docker-run-error-loading-shared-library-libstdc-so-6-and-libgcc-s-so-1/40496

> It looks like a missing runtime dependency in your final image. Try changing RUN apk add --no-cache openssl ncurses-libs to RUN apk add --no-cache openssl ncurses-libs libstdc++.

The fix being to add `libstdc++` to your install line.

The reasoning for this is also outlined in the forum post:

> The beam has native runtime dependencies and OTP 24 added libc as runtime dependency to support the JIT. With that change it seems like bare alpine:3.9 no longer brings all the required runtime dependencies. You’ll need to make sure that all of those those are present in the app container.

Best of luck!

Comment: Doesn't the second part of the Dockerfile already contains it ? Also, I tried to put in in the first part, but it didn't changed anything.

Comment: You need to add `libstd++` to the runtime. The first image is used in buildtime.